# How do I redirect after login using django while passing variables and saving to a database?

Tags: python, django, redirect, httpresponse

I am trying to allow a user to favorite a video while they're signed out.  I'm using @login_required to force the user to sign in, have the video saved to their account, and then redirect back to the page they were on.  I am getting an error saying

```
UnboundLocalError at /loggedout_fav/
local variable 'video' referenced before assignment
```

on the return line under loggedout_fav.  I put a print statement in the view but nothing is printing to the console either.  Any advice on how to fix it?

## html

```
<form method = 'post' action = '/loggedout_fav/'> {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" value="{{video}}" name = "video_add_loggedout"/>
    <input type='submit' value='Login to plate this video'/>
</form>
```

## url

```
url(r'^loggedout_fav/', 'loggedout_fav'),
```

## view

```
def loggedout_fav(request):
    if 'video_add_loggedout' in request.POST:
        video = request.POST['video_add_loggedout']
        print video
        print 'test'
        try:
            s = Everything.objects.get(profile = request.user, video = request.POST['video_add_loggedout'], playlist = 'Favorites', platform = 'youtube')
            print "already exists"
        except:
            p = Everything(profile = request.user, video = request.POST['video_add_loggedout'], playlist = 'Favorites', platform = 'youtube')
            p.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('reserve.views.trending_video_player', kwargs={'author':'youtube', 'video':video}))

def trending_video_player(request,author,video):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You used 'id' instead of 'name' ! So this is never True:

```
if 'video_add_loggedout' in request.POST:
```

And `video` is never set, so it chokes on (you should have posted the stacktrace BTW, I had to reverse that):

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('reserve.views.trending_video_player', kwargs={'author':'youtube', 'video':video}))
```

**First things first** you could fix your Python, like this:

```
def loggedout_fav(request):
    if 'video_add_loggedout' not in request.POST:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest()

    video = request.POST['video_add_loggedout']
    try:
        s = Everything.objects.get(profile = request.user, video = request.POST['video_add_loggedout'], playlist = 'Favorites', platform = 'youtube')
        print "already exists"
    except:
        p = Everything(profile = request.user, video = request.POST['video_add_loggedout'], playlist = 'Favorites', platform = 'youtube')
        p.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('reserve.views.trending_video_player', kwargs={'author':'youtube', 'video':video}))
```

**Of course**, fix your HTM too, this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{video}}" id = "video_add_loggedout"/>
```

Should be:

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{video}}" name="video_add_loggedout"/>
```

Comment: I changed it from id to name, but I still get the same error.  I think I am setting the video variable through " video = request.POST['video_add_loggedout']". In the console, I don't see the variable printed but I do see POST /accounts/login/ HTTP/1.1  and GET /loggedout_fav/ HTTP/1.1" 500 66320.  I'm able to sign-in as a user but not able to get to the actual view.

Comment: I don't know what to say. It looks like you were unable to read all my answer during the 2 minutes that you spent on it before your comment: 0. your python is still broken and 1. you did not post the stacktrace of the error and 2. your comment is cryptic.

Answer (score 0):

Save the values to the session. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/

Make sure you grab the values in the session before logging the user in so you won't lose them.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what jpic said might well be the problem. I post a separate answer to clarify the problem: The UnboundLocalError is a python error meaning that somewhere in your code you access a variable prior to defining it.

In your 'loggedout_fav' view code, I see you attempt to access the 'video' variable in the last line. When the `if 'video_add_loggedout' in request.POST` statement is not True (and therefore the nested block not executed), 'video' variable will not be initialized and this Exception will be raised. Practically this means that you attempt to access your view without posting a 'video_add_loggedout' variable. I would reorganize the view as follows:

```
def loggedout_fav(request):
    try:
        Everything.objects.get_or_create(profile=request.user, video=request.POST['video_add_loggedout'], playlist='Favorites', platform='youtube')
    except KeyError:
        #do something when the variable is not set. eg:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('reserve.views.trending_video_player', kwargs={'author':'youtube', 'video':request.POST['video_add_loggedout']}))
```

The above also demonstrates how you can use the `get_or_create` method to clean up your code a little.